# I have a class that I am using 4 times. Two of the Labels using the class work but when I add a new Label it does not work

Tags: vb.net, class

The code was working and then suddenly stopped for the newer Labels that I have added to the form.  It seems like the Timer code that subtracts the time and adds to the AccTimeStg is not being called.  The ArrayTimer works the Prefix text changes just fine so that timer is working.  So the First two Labels I have on the form do as they are coded to do.  I thought that when a change was made to a class and then a build was done the changes were made to all the objects that were using that class.  I tested that theory as well Being new to using classes, It worked that way.  I just don't understand how the old Labels are not affected but newer ones are not working.
Here is the code

```
Option Strict On
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class TimeLogLabel
    Inherits Label

    Private m_VaraibleToSet As Boolean
    <System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
    Public Property VaraibleToSet() As Boolean
        Get
            Return m_VaraibleToSet
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
            m_VaraibleToSet = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private m_PrefixText As String = "Prefix Text"
    <System.ComponentModel.Category("Control")> _
    Public Property PrefixText() As String
        Get
            Return m_PrefixText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_PrefixText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Class LogTime
        Private m_EventName As String
        Public Property EventName() As String
            Get
                Return m_EventName
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_EventName = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_StartT As String
        Public Property StartT() As String
            Get
                Return m_StartT
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_StartT = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_StopT As String
        Public Property StopT() As String
            Get
                Return m_StopT
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_StopT = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Private m_TSpan As String
        Public Property TSpan() As String
            Get
                Return m_TSpan
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                m_TSpan = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Sub New( _
            ByVal m_EventName As String, _
            ByVal m_StartT As String, _
            ByVal m_StopT As String, _
            ByVal m_TSpan As String)

            EventName = m_EventName
            StartT = m_StartT
            StopT = m_StopT
            TSpan = m_TSpan
        End Sub
    End Class

    '***********************
    Private Timer As Timer
    Private ArrayTimer As Timer
    Public StartTime As Date
    Public StopTime As Date
    Public AccTimeStg As String
    Public TimeArray(19) As String
    Private Ons As Boolean

    Public Sub New()
        Timer = New Timer
        Timer.Interval = 1
        AddHandler Timer.Tick, AddressOf Timer_Tick
        ArrayTimer = New Timer
        ArrayTimer.Interval = 100
        ArrayTimer.Enabled = True
        AddHandler ArrayTimer.Tick, AddressOf ArrayTimer_Tick
    End Sub

    Public TimeList As List(Of LogTime) = New List(Of LogTime)
    Dim EventId As Integer

    Public Sub StartTimer()
        If Ons = False Then
            Ons = True
            EventId = EventId + 1
            StartTime = Now
            AddLog(TimeArray, PrefixText & ": Start Time " & StartTime)
            TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText & " " & EventId, "Start Time " & StartTime, "", ""))
            Timer.Enabled = True
            Timer.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub StopTimer()
        If Ons = True Then
            Ons = False
            EventId = EventId + 1
            StopTime = Now
            AddLog(TimeArray, PrefixText & ": Stop Time " & StopTime & " Up Time " & AccTimeStg)
            TimeList.Add(New LogTime(PrefixText & " " & EventId, "", "Stop Time " & StopTime, " Up Time " & AccTimeStg))
            Timer.Enabled = False
            Timer.Stop()
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        Dim TimeSpan As TimeSpan = Now.Subtract(StartTime)
        AccTimeStg = TimeSpan.Days & " : " & TimeSpan.Hours & " : " & TimeSpan.Minutes & " : " & TimeSpan.Seconds
    End Sub

    Private Sub ArrayTimer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        '''' Me.Text = String.Join("XX", TimeList)
        ' this is the normal Me.text
        Me.Text = PrefixText & " " & AccTimeStg
    End Sub

    Private Sub AddLog(ByVal logAsArray() As String, ByVal newEntry As String)
        For index As Integer = logAsArray.Length - 1 To 1 Step -1
            logAsArray(index) = logAsArray(index - 1)
        Next
        logAsArray(0) = newEntry
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please re-arange your text into paragraphs and shorten your code to the bare minimum that can explain the problem.

Comment: Check to make sure that the Tick events of the Timer objects are actually wired up to something (like `Handles Timer.Tick`) - just naming subs `Timer_Tick` won't cause them to be triggered when the event happens.

Comment: back to `m_` variables - yuck!

Comment: @Ben N That is exactly what I thought. So I Added

     'Public Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick'

This gives me an error.  Handles clause requires a WithEvents variable defined in the containing type or its containing base types

Comment: @OneFineDay m_ variables?? I am new at vb Classes and not sure what you mean by yuck.. If there is a better way to write this code I would love to know.  I got this code from on this site and got a half of an answer on it so I adapted it and made it work.  I am very open for suggestions not rudeness

Comment: That kind of naming convention makes variable less readable. Not rude - my opinion!

Comment: OK Sorry for the comment!!! I am new at this site and have had a lot of cracks made at me...  Or I will ask a question and not get a full answer so. I am a PLC programmer and now just into vb.net for about a year or so.. Completely self taught so I am open to any comments about how to be a better programmer. So thanks How should I make them readable?

Comment: `Or I will ask a question and not get a full answer`  in this case, you havent actually asked a question, just dumped some code with some unpunctuated, rambling text.  See [Ask]

Comment: I reformatted the code a little by adding some blank lines for readability.  If you disagree with the edits, you can roll it back.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out. With the help of @Ben N THX

```
Private WithEvents Timer As Timer
Private WithEvents ArrayTimer As Timer
```

was needed to use the handles

```
Public Sub Timer_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer.Tick
```